# Where to store shared resources files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, fs

We have 2 nodejs apps (on 2 different servers) that use same resources (some json files).
We need to access those shared files from the applications **code**. That's why we want to move them out.

What is the correct way to do that? Is this architecturally correct?

1. SFTP server?
2. S3?
3. Other option?

We use AWS cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can use s3 bucket for storing the file. I kind of did a project where we had two nodejs application where we had to provide a kind of key to both apps which was then hosted on s3 and retrieved when needed. You can also do this locally is you are hosting both node apps on a single machine

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option by far is S3.  An alternative would be to create an EFS filesystem and mount it on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Options: EFS - mount a file system; S3 - store as objects in shared bucket; DynamoDB - store json as documents in NoSQL DB. You didn't mention, but I assume you're running on an EC2 fleet and not going serverless, so S3 or dynamo would be good choices -- you can provide security by limiting permissions with EC2-assigned IAM roles.

Comment: We run EC2 instance with autoscaling and codeDeploy, not beanstalk and not fleet

Comment: Thanks. Is this architecturally correct (S3)? These files necessary for the system

Comment: It's fine architecture unless you have a requirement for very low latency, in which case I would suggest high-thruput EFS with EC2s with lots of provisioned iops. Or randomize the prefix in S3 to help retrieval.